# How do I run a batch file at a specific time?

Tags: command, time, batch-jobs

I have tried using the `batch` and `at` commands with no luck. I have a batch file in a location, lets say "$DD/batchfile.batch". Here is what I have tried.

```
batch -f $DD/batchfile.batch 10:00 today
at -f $DD/batchfile.batch 10:00 today
```

While it will add the job, and I can see it under `atq`, it doesn't seem to execute the batch. When the time comes, nothing happens and the batch is removed from queue. If I run the batch file on its own in a terminal, it properly executes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Suggest you post the contents of an example $DD/batchfile.batch which is not working, and a `ls -l $DD/batchfile.batch`

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing what's in the file.  Did `at` send mail?  If not, does sending mail to `$LOGNAME` using `sendmail` work?  Did `at` leave anything in syslog?  Create a minimal reproducible example, e.g. `echo 'echo true' | at now + 1 minute` for testing; does that work?  Then build up from there until you have a failure.

Comment: Also - examine the file created in `/var/spool/cron/atjobs/` and/or try running it (as user, perhaps with `sh -x` for tracing).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I guess that your OS is some flavor of Linux.</sup>

Be sure that your `$DD/batchfile.batch` file exists and is readable & executable.

I believe that your [batch(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_batch.htm) job is started. Perhaps it is exited quickly (e.g. because the [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) for batch jobs is perhaps not your interactive `PATH`, or because your environment is not the same as in interactive shells - see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)).
You might start your script with some [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) command to get some logging message in your system logs and/or at some redirected prints early in it. You could also start your batch job with something like

```
 /bin/date +"start of my batch %c%n" > /tmp/batchstart.stamp
 echo path is $PATH >> /tmp/batchstart.stamp
 /usr/bin/printenv >> /tmp/batchstart.stamp
```

and check later that `/tmp/batchstart.stamp`  exists and look inside it using some editor (like `emacs` or `gedit`) or pager (like `less`)

BTW, `batch`, `at` & [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) jobs are often sending email (to your account on the *local* machine). Did you install some (perhaps simple) SMTP server on your local machine? Do you have a valid mail account or alias (e.g. in `/etc/aliases`)?

Also, look inside your system log files (often, under `/var/log/` e.g. `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/daemon.log` or `/var/log/auth.log`)